# No pokestop drops for a day?

Tags: pokemon-go

I haven't been able to get any drops for a whole day now, is anyone else experiencing this? I've tried multiple stops, restating app and phone, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you sure that the items are not just going into your inventory? I went out earlier and spun a Pokestop, nothing happened but the items were added to my inventory.

Comment: Are you using a GPS spoofing app?  I've seen people talking about soft bans when that's detected.

Comment: @Taegost, I've used one but that a few hours ago, so you know how long the soft ban last? Thanks.

Comment: @Sean they aren't in my inventory either.

Comment: I've heard it's typically 30 minutes, but I would assume that it could be permanent if it was particularly egregious.  I don't have anything definitive to back that up though, just anecdotes and personal experience with other games

Comment: @RustyMembers If it's anything like Ingress, expect a permanent ban.

Comment: I'd wait a day to make sure, but if you're still banned by then you can bet it's probably permanent. As Sean said, if it's like Ingress then you're out of luck. Time to get a new account and not cheat this time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a maximum number of items you can have in your bag. By default this is 250 but you can upgrade it in the shop.

This also happens when the servers are experiencing problems or you've been travelling to fast (e.g. car or train).

Comment: Backpack got plenty of space, and I'm sitting still :)